# Is the Unix "realpath" command distributed with macOS Ventura?

Tags: terminal, command-line, monterey, ventura

I haven't upgraded from macOS 12.6 to Ventura yet.

I have no `realpath` command in my `/bin` directory, or anywhere else on my M1 MacBook Air.

I've never installed brew/homebrew on my Mac though I've been told by other developers that brew can't install anything in `/bin` anyway.

But another developer who has upgraded to Ventura tells me there is a `realpath` in their `/bin` and it's signed with the Identifier `com.apple.realpath`

Can anybody confirm that `realpath` did not come with macOS Monterrey but has been added to macOS Ventura?

Comment: /bin/realpath is there in my Ventura on an M1 mini

Comment: And on my Ventura Intel Macs. Since realpath is part of POSIX and macOS is POSIX compliant, I assume it has always been there (but maybe not).

Comment: Interesting... I'm still on Monterey (Intel Mac) and can confirm that there is no command `realpath`.

Comment: And Homebrew installs it as `/usr/local/bin/realpath`

Comment: @jaume It's absent here on ARM Monterey, too. @glennjackman That's the path on Intel; on ARM Homebrew uses (by default) `/opt/homebrew/bin/`.

Comment: I have an ARM machine on Monterey and realpath is present

Comment: @Ezekiel Is it present in `/bin` or in `/opt/homebrew/bin`? Or somewhere else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac would seem to be an extensive answer to **this** question but not to OP's **actual** question.

Comment: I also have it in M1 Ventura in `/bin` but not `/opt/homebrew/bin`.

Comment: @hippietrail Mine is in `/bin`

Comment: Is XCode installing the `realpath` binary?  I'm not going to install XCode to find out, but it seems reasonable that it might?  All three of my Monterey machines (1x M1, 2x Intel, all 12.6.1) do not have it.

Comment: @MarcWilson: I wondered that too. I've had Xcode installed since I got this laptop but I haven't upgraded past 13.4.1 yet since I'll have to dig out some external drives to make enough space temporarily.

Comment: No, XCode is not installing `realpath`, you can take a look running `ls -1 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`. `realpath` was indeed introduced in macOS Ventura 13.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the headline question: Yes.

On an Intel Mac (I can't see why an M1 Mac would be different):

1. My macOS 13 has `/bin/realpath`.
2. The executable has the same date and time as **all** other files in /usr/bin. Here is an `ls` snippet.

```
-rwsr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   203584 18 Oct 23:36 ps
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   134064 18 Oct 23:36 pwd
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   133840 18 Oct 23:36 realpath
-rwxr-xr-x   2 root  wheel   135424 18 Oct 23:36 rm
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   133808 18 Oct 23:36 rmdir
```

3. `/bin` is only on the sealed system volume, so nothing apart from a macOS install or update could have put `realpath` in `/bin`.
4. I am a homebrew user, but there is no homebrew version of `realpath`:

```
% brew info realpath
Error: No available formula with the name "realpath".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
```

Note that it is true (see @nohillside's comment) that realpath can be installed by brew as part of coreutils. I suggest caution with coreutils because of the potential for name clashes.

5. @Barmar has commented above that `realpath` is in `/bin` on M1 Ventura.
6. I have a copy of all macOS 12 man pages. There is no man page for `realpath`. (This is a slightly indirect way of saying not present in Monterey).
7. There are new questions popping up on the web about `realpath` and Ventura. This also indicates that it was not installed previously.

I conclude that:

1. `realpath` is part of macOS 13 on both Intel and AS.
2. `realpath` was not in macOS 12.
3. `realpath` is not in homebrew as a distinct item.

Comment: In Homebrew, `realpath` is part of `coreutils` (and it doesn't know about firmlinks). Does `man realpath` on macOS 13 imply that it does?

Comment: `man realpath` says "The realpath utility uses the realpath(3) function to resolve all symbolic links...". No mention of firmlinks - so I assume not.

Comment: `brew info coreutils` has warnings about conflicting binaries and adding a leading `g` to some names (likely not yet to its `realpath`). Use coreutils with care.

Comment: The reason I'm delving into all this is because the Swift directory-walking functionality does not follow symlinks or firmlinks but I don't think we have its source to see its implementation. Rust's directory-walker does follow firmlinks, leading to duplicate traversals. Its realpath doesn't resolve firmlinks. Zig's dir-walker also follows firmlinks but its realpath *does* resolve firmlinks. I'm down the rabbithole trying to figure out which language's standard library might be missing what funcitonality.

Comment: @hippietrail It‘s in the nature of firmlinks that standard unix library functions are not aware of their existence. But in general, questions about how library handle firmlinks are better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: @nohillside: Yes I'm asking programming questions about the `realpath()` standard library function on StackOverflow but questions about the macOS version of the `realpath` shell command here. Sometimes I post a bit of explanation in case people think I'm asking an X/Y question.

Comment: Note the realpath binary is not part od POSIX - the command line glags differ between GNU and macOS e.g. -f . man only gives the C function call.

Comment: `realpath` introduced in macOS Ventura 13.0 (October 2022), `readlink -f` introduced in macOS Monterey 12.3 (March 2022), see also [Which macOS version introduced "readlink -f"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464136/which-macos-version-introduced-readlink-f)